# Cordova plugin email composer not sending email

Tags: cordova, email, cordova-plugins

I'm install https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer in Visual Studio 2015 aplication for android

and add

```
function sendEmail() {


            cordova.plugins.email.isServiceAvailable(
                function (isAvailable) {
                    alert('isAvailable');

                    cordova.plugins.email.open({
                        to: ['mymail@gmail.com'],
                        subject: 'EmailComposer plugin test',
                        body: '<h2>Hello!</h2>This is <strong>HTML</strong>',
                        isHtml: true
                    }, callback);
                }


            );
```

After call function don't receive any error but email not receive on my address.

Any additional settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After call function don't receive any error but email not receive on my address.

If you are not receiving the alert message `isAvailable`. Your phone is probably not capable to send Emails. Please see [Determine if the device is capable to send emails](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#determine-if-the-device-is-capable-to-send-emails).

If you did receive that `isAvailable` message. `cordova.plugins.email.open` only ask you to choose which Email app you will use to open the Email draft. The 'send' decision is made by user. I tested on my android device, it works fine.